# When should you use Scoped in a .netcore API?

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, asp.net-core-2.0

When the webapi handles a request it uses `AsyncLocal`- meaning, all singletons in the container are scoped to the request implicitly.

In what situation would you register a Scoped service?

Comment: Where did you come up with *all singletons in the container are scoped to the request implicitly*?

Comment: Because of the definition of `AsyncLocal`. A singleton's lifecycle should begin at the first get and end when the application ends- unless i'm misunderstanding .netcore's definition of `singleton`. But since the container context is created within the scope of `AsyncLocal` (and therefor the async thread flow of a request) it is what I assumed was `scoped` to begin with. Now `scoped` as an option doesn't make sense with .netcore api.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that AsyncLocal provides a way to solve a "problem" with thread static vars when async await is used.  In an async await scenario the code execution may end on a different thread than it started on so the ending code may be out of scope for a thread static var set by the code earlier in the request.  The solution (as I understand it) to such an issue is to use an AsyncLocal var rather than a thread static var.

This is a totally different thing than a scoped service.  The goal of a scoped service is to have the same object from the DI container used for the duration of the request.  It's true that this must handle async await scenarios, but it also handles simpler cases where a service is injected into more than one method and you want the same object used if it's during the same request.

The two concepts, AsyncLocal and scoped service, are really quite different.  Does that help?